# Please help me to insert multiple values within the: $query->execute(array());

Tags: sql, arrays, pdo, insert, execute

I have this bit of PDO that I'm trying to insert into a very simple SQL Database.
The Console shows that from PHP, print_r() gives me exactly the response I'm hoping for,
however - the fields are not inserting into my SQL dBase.

Please, what am I doing wrong with this?:

I have two pictures, if this will help:

Response:
http://extoleducation.ipage.com/extol/test/functioning/test/pic1.png

dBase:
http://extoleducation.ipage.com/extol/test/functioning/test/pic2.png

```html
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=extoleducation.ipagemysql.com;dbname=trialdb","username","password");

if(isset($_POST['sample1'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `sampletable` (`sampleline1`, 'sampleline2', 'sampleline3', 'sampleline4') VALUES (:sample1, :sample2, :sample3, :sample4)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':sample1'=>$_POST['sample1'],':sample2'=>$_POST['sample2'],':sample3'=>$_POST['sample3'],':sample4'=>$_POST['sample4']));
 print_r($_POST['sample1'], $_POST['sample2'], $_POST['sample3'],$_POST['sample4']);
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but you're using single quotes (') as well as backticks (`) in your insert query. Try to use only backticks and give it a try.

Comment: Brilliant! That did it, thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the single quotes (') to backticks (`) was the solution. Thank you B_CooperA